# Google Cloud Remote Jupyter Notebook- Kernel Not Connecting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket, jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

When using a GCP AI Platform Jupyter Lab I am experiencing a unresponsive Jupyter Notebook.

The jupyter notebook is accessed over https (using the Open Jupyterlab button in GCP AI Platform).

The notebook says "Kernel Connecting" for several minutes before saying "Kernel Disconnected" in the status window.  When inspecting the browser error messages, it is reporting the below error message:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://475211ea312377e9-dot-us-east1.notebooks.googleusercontent.com/api/kernels/e77c9731-fc84-48d0-89ae-dfba685c37c1/channels?session_id=a6e7c6a9-ac86-4723-b435-74ca34036ded' failed:     _createSocket   @   default.js:73
```

I am using the basic Python 3 image with no special settings.

I am accessing the jupyter notebook from a Windows 10 Pro Corporate computer behind a corporate firewall / proxy.

When trying to access the jupyter notebook on an android phone, the jupyter notebook works fine, but when using company laptop, it is not working.  I have tried modifying several firewall settings, but still not able to connect.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue?  Any ideas on how I can resolve the issue and connect via Windows corporate laptop?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at WebSockets connections, as your test implied the connections are blocked by your Firewall. I would recommend to open a case with the Firewall vendor, check Websocket settings. If WS is not supported, I would use SSH to connect to it.

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/ssh-access

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have successfully connected to jupyter lab using SSH and port forwarding.  It did take some time to figure out how to use windows putty to set the http proxy alongside google cloud sdk "gcloud compute ssh" command, but finally got it working!  I will also talk to my IT department about the websocket settings, because I think it is very useful for non technical users to be able to just click "open jupyter lab" and view a jupyter notebook in GCP.  I will post my step by step in this thread for future reference.

Comment: @JesseNicholson - Can you please detail out the steps to followed to get your Jupyter working?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple Remote [Utility](https://github.com/korniichuk/rk) to connect to the Jupyter Notebook. GCP recommend to use [SSH](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/ssh-access#no-https-access) to connect Kernel from remote.